# The menu of my site doesn't look right when I view it on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ios, ipad, ipod-touch

When I view [www.americaspoeticsoul.com](http://americaspoeticsoul.com) on my iPhone, the menu overflows for some reason. See:

[image: Menu overflows on iPhone]

And it even looks worst on the other pages because of the title:

[image: Worst on other pages - overflows over the header]

Anyone know why it's like this? And is there a way to fix it? Here's the CSS for the menu:

```
/*Menu*/

#menu {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    width:450px;
}

#menu ul { /* remove bullets and list indents */
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    float:left;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#D41C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#menu ul li a.current_link {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:2px;
    background-color:#FF1C1C;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: You're discovering one of the downsides of relying on text/fonts within your menu system.  There is way too much variability (OS, browser, device, etc.) to expect the text to always behave properly or even use the font you intended.  I use a graphically created menu system which never changes no matter what and a simple text menu in the footer as a fallback.

Comment: @Sparky672 I see what you mean. That might take some time to design the backgrounds and the hover-overs in PhotoShop but I'll try it.  (I'm not that good in designing graphics but I'm going to do it for this menu)

Comment: I think you'll be happier with the end result, your new level of control, and you'll have learned a different technique.  Since you may end up taking my advice, I posted my comment as an answer.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're discovering one of the downsides of relying on text/fonts within your menu system. There is way too much variability (OS, browser, device, etc.) to expect the text to always behave properly or even use the font you intended.

I use a graphically created menu system which never changes no matter what and a simple text menu in the footer as a fallback.

Comment: But, the only problem is when someone wants to translate the page, the menu doesn't get translated.

Comment: @Nathan:  Yes, but that's what the small text menu in the footer is for.

Answer (score 4):

As an iPhone user and developer - I wouldn't use a site like yours on the phone unless I *really* had to - it would require all sorts of zooming in before I could read or click on that menu.

If you have content that you would like to present via a menu on an iPhone, I would recommend detecting small-screen mobile browsers and redirecting them to a mobile specific menu at the very least - jQuery Mobile is *so* easy to use to create a menu.

This is just a response about iPhone or similar size screens - I'm sure you'd want to fix this on an iPad if it looks the same.

Comment: +1, This is also why I use a graphical menu system rather than one based on text.  There is way too much OS variability when your menu relies upon text/fonts.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't either but I was just going to it to see and the menu is messed up. I saw in the analytics people are visiting it on iPhones and iPads. So I need to fix it on iPads too. But I don't have an iPad so I will have to find one of those sites that replicate the iPad to test it. (I'm sure that wont work though because it's just an iframe within the iPad frame) This actually isn't my site, I made it for someone else.

Comment: @Sparky672 So should I just use background images instead? That would kinda be a lot of work but it would make it better so it has rounded corners in every browser - even the crappy browsers.

Comment: @Nathan - The suggestion below about setting an explicit width makes sense - but I'm not a CSS expert.  You might find it works fine on iPads anyway - visit an Apple store or a Best Buy for a quick check.

Comment: @iandotkelly I'm going to an Apple store this weekend so I'll check it out then. (there are hardly any Apple stores around where I live. I have to go to the bigger cities)

Comment: @Sparky - graphical menu's are not very friendly with respect to accessibility, or translation to other languages.  But I agree your point - OS and browser variability is a pain.

Comment: @Nathan:  Yes, I would.  See my comment on your OP.

Comment: @iandotkelly: I know, but if design is important, go graphical and you can just use a simple text-based fallback menu in the footer.

Comment: @Sparky - I work for a company that specializes in accessibility - so I guess I have a different perspective.  With more modern browsers (i.e. after IE7) font control is so much more standard than it used to be and CSS standards are fairly well supported.  I used to do graphical menu's but I wouldn't touch them now.

Comment: @iandotkelly:  Yet despite better CSS font control, you still recommend creating a whole different site just for mobile devices.  I'm not disputing your point but the whole point of "mobile Safari" is to render mobile specific sites obsolete and if the site doesn't miniaturize well, then just tweak the site.  (no, I'm not opposed to mobile versions of certain sites but not every site needs to go this way.)

Comment: @sparky - but the recommendation for a mobile oriented menu isn't about CSS font control - he could fix the site so it looks the same on the iPhone - but the buttons and the text will still be tiny and need you to zoom in to read and click.  Its about supporting tiny screens (if he wants to).

Comment: @iandotkelly:  And that's also the main downside to using a miniature browser... everything is rendered in miniature.  It's certainly not ideal but it's expected.  Again, I'm not disputing your answer, I up-voted it, but creating a whole second website for mobile devices is not always worth the trouble.

Comment: @Sparky - hey, I'm not arguing either - I agree, supporting mobile devices is a pain, and perhaps not worth it unless you really need to.

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of the iPhone's multi-touch "pinch-to-zoom" feature. I use it all the time on websites in Mobile Safari. I can still read the text when it's zoomed out but I prefer zooming in since it's so easy. That navigation is actually pretty easy to use on the iPhone but I just had to figure out how to get it to stop overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting an explicit width on the menu items which leaves their width at the mercy of the browser and how large the font-size + margins and padding end up being. In the case of mobile browsers (Android too), your width is just too much for the 450px that you have. Try dropping the font size a point or something.

Comment: I'll try  making the font size smaller.

Comment: I made the font-size 14px instead of 15px and it actually works. But I don't know about other phones so I'm going to use images. I voted yours up since it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this to your CSS file:

html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none; }

This will stop Mobile Safari (and Windows Phone) from adjusting the size of your text in an attempt to make it more readable.

EDIT: If you only want to affect the text-size-adjust on mobile phones, you could use a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

  html { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none; }
}
```

If you're feeling ambitious, you should consider adjusting the layout on a more fundamental level for smaller screen sizes. Any CSS you put inside that media query will get applied to devices that have a screen size of 480px or less.

For example, the buttons may be a bit too small for fingers to reliably tap on them. A better alternative would be to linearize the layout so that there's only one column and each link button takes up the full width of the screen.

Comment: Whilst this would maintain the aesthetics of the page, it would consequently make the site less usable.

Comment: The major downside is that this also prevents the text from re-sizing in the desktop version of Safari when he tries to zoom; text stays exactly the same.  Yes, I just tested this on my site.

Comment: Can I just do this for the menu and not the whole page?

Comment: Sure, just replace "html" with "#menu".